# How to mathematically color the regions bounded by a parametric curve?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions, plane-curves

Usually, if an implicit equation $F(x, y) = 0$ defines a curve (or curves) on the x-y plane, then we can use the inequalities $F(x, y) < 0$ or $F(x, y) > 0$ to color the regions bounded by the curve (or curves). In this way, we can make interesting pictures.

Suppose $(x, y) = (f(t), g(t))$ defines a parametric curve ([an example picture](http://i1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd371/benice_chen/parametric_curve.png)) on the plane. **How to color the regions** ([an example picture](http://i1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd371/benice_chen/parametric_region.png)) **bounded by the curve without converting the parametric equation to an implicit equation?**

Answer (score 2):

Given a closed curve $\gamma: t\mapsto{\bf z}(t)$ $\ (0\leq t\leq T)$  in the plane under mild technical conditions for each point $c=(a,b)\notin\{{\bf z}(t)\ |\ t\in [0,T]\}$ the winding number $n_\gamma(c)$ is defined by
$$n_\gamma(c):={1\over 2\pi}\int_0^T {(y(t)-b)\dot x(t)-(x(t)-a)\dot y(t)\over (x(t)-a)^2+(y(t)-b)^2}\ dt ={1\over 2\pi i}\int_\gamma{dz\over z-c}\ .$$
This number is always an integer (this is a miracle). Color  the point $c$ green if $n_\gamma(c)$ is odd and white otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the winding number to discriminate among the regions.  If we use complex numbers to represent the plane, the winding number of the closed parametric curve $z = \gamma(t)$, $0 \le t \le 1$, around a point $a$ not on the curve is 
$$n(\gamma;a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{z-a} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma'(t)\ dt}{\gamma(t)-a}$$
which should take integer values (so you can use numerical methods to calculate this approximately and round to the nearest integer).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply.